# how to close jquery dialog box from a partialview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having a partialview A on my main view page. from this Partialview I m opening a jquery
dialogbox which opens a partialview inside it.
I m having some buttons inside that partialview which are meant to do some task
When I click on the button the event are firing but when I try to close the dialog box by the code given below I get error.
If I press escape when the dialog box opens it closes but When I click on the button to get it back it again gives the same error.
ie- when I can open the dialog box only once.

```
$(function () {
    $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 700,
        resizable: false,
        modal: false,
        open: function (event, ui) { $(this).load('<%=Url.Action("PushButton","Body",new {Parm="text",Parm1="para"}) %>'); },
        buttons: {Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        position: 'top',
        closeOnEscape: true
    });
});
```

This is how I m opening it

```
$('#dialog').dialog('open');
```

This is the function through which I m trying to close it, this is on the partialview which is opening in dialog box

```
$('#dialog').dialog('close');
```

I have tried to make a function on the partialview A(from where I click and get and the dialog box but getting the same error)
This is the error I m getting

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Kindly help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
buttons: {
    Cancel: function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have mention the error as well means to say I m getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the return value from the dialog to a variable like this:

```
var dialogRef;

$(function () {
    dialogRef = $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 700,
        resizable: false,
        modal: false,
        buttons: {Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        position: 'top',
        closeOnEscape: true
    });

     $("#innerButton").on("click", function() {
        dialogRef.dialog("close");
     });
});
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mWGYs/)